# How to stop Spark Streaming context when the network connection (TCP IP) is closed?

Tags: hadoop, streaming, apache-spark

In other words Instead of setting 'duration' in Spark streaming context to a value, I want to set it to (socket close time - socket open time)

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [StreamingListner](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.StreamingListener) interface to listen for the receiver being disconencted, and then shutdown the streaming context.

This is used as

```
// define listener
class MyListener extends StreamingListener {
  override def onReceiverStopped(...) {
    streamingContext.stop()
  }
} 

// attach listener
streamingContext. addStreamingListener(new MyListener())
```

Answer (score 0):

By doing ssc.stop() in streaming listener, when ur streaming got error or teriminated this function will trigger to stop. There's another triggers like when the batch started,finished,etc.

```
    ssc.addStreamingListener(new StreamingListener() {

    @Override
      public void onReceiverError(StreamingListenerReceiverError receiverError) {
      System.out.println("Do what u want");
      ssc.stop();
      }

    @Override
      public void onReceiverStopped(StreamingListenerReceiverStopped receiverStopped) {
      System.out.println("Do what u want");
      ssc.stop(true,true); 
      }
    }

    ssc.start();
```